# pexpect for passwordless access does not work

Tags: python, pexpect

I have this:

```
vmA --connected --vmB
```

access from vmA to vmB is passwordless. Basically when I run from vmA it takes me to the vmB prompt directly:

```
ssh root@vmB
[root@vmB ~]#
```

Now in vmA I have this below pexpect script, but this does not allow me to log into the vmB and run any commands. The command which I am trying to run on vmB actually getting executed on vmA.
Where am I going wrong ? ANy help much appreciated ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn("ssh root@3.3.3.4")
child.expect('#')
child.sendline("ls")
child.expect('#')
print child.before
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the prompt that I was expecting was ('$') different from the example code that I gave above. Now in expect ('$') is treated as a regex instead of a literal string.

Changing the expect prompt to ('\$') resolved the issue